# "interested" or "interesting" in this context

Tags: tense, past-participles, formal-language

I am writing this context:

> Dear Mr. XXX.
>
> I am XXX from Italy.
>
> I am applying for XXXXX. I am very **interested** in the Master program "MA in Business computer science", which its subject code is 11.9.
>   I followed the website, that is specified in the excel document posted on XXXX website, and I just found a Germany version of the program. I tried to click on "English" button, but I didn't get the English version.
>
> Kindly would you tell me where can I find a description in English for that program please?
>
> I really appreciate you help.
>
> Thank you very much.

Should the bold word be "interesting"? or "interested"?

Comment: You want to use *interested*. You are *interested* in something because it is *interesting*.

Comment: Side note: Don't say "which its subject code is". Try, "... with subject code of 11.9" or "... which is subject code 11.9" or simply "MA in Business Computer Science, subject code 11.9". Or end the sentence before "which" and then write "It's subject code is 11.9". In general, "which" should not be followed by what would otherwise be a complete sentence: the phrase following "which", at least in a context like this, should not have a subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Interested**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/interested?s=t) means having an interest in something. Some [examples](http://www.reference.com/example-sentences/interested).

[**Interesting**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/interesting?s=t) means engaging or exciting and holding the attention or curiosity. Some [examples](http://www.reference.com/example-sentences/interesting).

So in your case if you write like

> I am very interested in XXX subject. [✓]

Again if you write like

> I find XXX subject very interesting and also want to pursue a
>   degree... [✓]

Answer (score 2):

You would use "interested" because you are expressing an interest IN something. You would use "interesting" to describe someone or something that is able to hold someone's attention.