# An interesting teacher VS an interested student

Tags: participles, modifiers, morphology

We know an adjective ending in either -ing or -ed can modify a noun. What is the difference between these two pairs?

> An interesting teacher
>
> An interested student

> A heartbroken mother       ( A heartbreaking mother? )
>
> A heartbreaking moment     ( A heartbroken moment? )

Both the first pair can modify a person, yet I'm not sure whether the second pair can do the same.

Comment: Have you looked up the definitions of these words?

Comment: "Constance was a heartbreaking woman, full of fire and bile, but with a necessary yearning for justice. " The Guardian

Comment: Roughly, **-ing** means "doing the action", and **-ed** means "having the action done to them."

Comment: @stangdon How does -ing mean doing the action??

Comment: @Lambie A running man: doing the action called "run".  A heartbreaking moment: a moment that breaks hearts.  etc.

Comment: @KateBunting, I know the difference between these words when they are placed after linking verbs to modify the subject. But I can't recognize in what situations an adjective ending in -ing can't serve as a modifier that modifies a person or an adjective ending in -ed can't modify a thing.

Comment: _I can't recognize in what situations a present participle can't serve as a modifier that modifies a person._ It depends on whether the verb in question makes sense in that context. A person who evokes strong and painful emotions in others can be described as _heartbreaking_, but a moment doesn't have a heart to be (metaphorically) broken.

Comment: @stangdon I think the word  doing needs quotation marks.

Comment: The so-called "present participle" (_-ing_ form) is better called an "active participle"; and the so-called "past particple" (_-ed, -en_ form) is better called a "passive participle".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["interested" or "interesting" in this context.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15273/interested-or-interesting-in-this-context)  Also [Why are we using "interested" instead "interesting" in the next phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/231908/) and ['feel interesting vs feel interested'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/), among others.

Comment: Also related: [Adjectives ending in -ed and -ing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89784/adjectives-ending-in-ed-and-ing/89785#89785)

Comment: @FumbleFingers， Thanks for your  recommendation of those sources. They are mainly about the participles( -ed and-ing form) which serve as predicative( I knew the difference), but my question is about the participles which serve as modifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a verb in its **past participle** form *(interested, heartbroken)* is modifying a noun, it implies a *subjective (inward) effect on the noun*, while in its **present participle** form (*interesting, heartbreaking)*, the verb implies a more *objective (outwards) effect on the noun*.

Therefore, *a heartbroken mother* means that **the mother is suffering** from her broken heart (either literally or metaphorically). You can say *a heartbreaking mother* to show that **the actions of said mother is perhaps heartbreaking to witness**, though this construction, at least to my ears, feels a bit weird. The same is true for *a heartbreaking moment*: **it is heartbreaking for other people to witness** (maybe even for oneself); the moment cannot feel or suffer, therefore *<s>a heartbroken moment</s>* would be ungrammatical.

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

A **heartbroken** mother: Her heart was broken **by something**.

An **interested** student: The student *has an interest in something* or **is interested in something**. [Not much used in English except in cases like: The *interested party* in legal language. The party with an interest in some matter.]

An **interesting** teacher: There teacher arouses interest in what he/she teaches.
A *heartbreaking* moment: A moment that breaks hearts.

The past participle is a "plain" adjective describing the noun and usually can be shown to have done something to the noun.

The gerund form implies the noun is "doing" something.

- The **jumping** cat was a joy to see.

The past participle implies the noun has got a state or condition.

- The **muted** strains of classical music could be heard on the second floor.